# Difference between "Signals" (js-signals) and "Observables" (mobx, mobx-react)?

Tags: user-interface, signals, editor, mobx, mobx-react

## Could they work together for a perfect states management and bidirectional data binding?

Mobx implements observable pattern in javascript. By using mobx and mobx-react, people can refer mobx observables in react and assign autorun, reaction, and comptued routines to them. Every time an observable changes its references relationship, autorun, reaction and computed routines fired.

This is really helpful when you developed a rich content application, say editor.

While js-signals works differently, a signal can register callbacks and its priority. When a component changes, a programmer have a choice to dispatch the signal to fire all associated callbacks (just like events)

Which pattern is better, could they work together smoothly?

## Background

I am working on an editor which uses signals intensively. I also prefer to use observable patterns to manage states of the editor. My personal feelings, when the observable grows up (just like 200 global variables), it becomes hard to maintain.

I am appreciated for your thoughts. Developers who succeeded in using  those techniques are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

js-signals is just an event emitter library and mobx is just a state/observer libary.

You can simply fire and handle events. as long as the handler wraps the changes of mobx State in a mobx.action. the changes in state are handled properly and react components are updated properly/observer events fired properly:

```
class Store {
  @mobx.observable name = "test"
}
var store = new Store();
//custom object that dispatch a `started` signal
var myObject = {
  started : new signals.Signal()
};
function onStarted(name){
  mobx.runInAction(() => {
    store.name = name;
  });
}
myObject.started.add(onStarted); //add listener

mobx.observe(store,"name",change=> {
  myObject.started.dispatch(change.name+'x'); //woops now we have an infinite loop!
});
myObject.started.dispatch('foo'); //dispatch signal passing custom parameters
// myObject.started.remove(onStarted); //remove a single listener
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! It is great you know well both of them. I cannot get you point why you illustrated it with an infinite loop. Did you mean I should not use them together? Here is what I am thinking about: if a state determined by multiple observables' changes and a state influence multiple actions, I might as well use mobx reaction to notify a signal to dispatch registered callbacks. For example, script codes change => (redo grammar checking, re-render the output). There could be many ways to fire (redo grammar checking, re-render the output). Signal might be cleaner

Comment: @WangYi if you can just do it with mobx i would just use mobx. it is transactional so it wont trigger observe triggers twice if you update same variable twice in same (trans)action. on that: always derive state that can be derived/`computed`. and for the rest use observe triggers.

Comment: i have no experience of js-signals, just took the example from the home page: https://millermedeiros.github.io/js-signals/ . My experiens of event-emiitters though is that it gets real messy reall quick. there is no typed structure so easily you can end up making code mistakes and typo's.

Comment: understood now. Please give me some time, let me to do something so that the concept of combination could  be programmatically expressed.

Comment: @WangYi i only used infinite loop in example to display dangers of using  events. it's fine to mix both like this.